# Update records in access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

While clicking BUTTON not updating records.

The error message is:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

My code is given below, in VB 2005 with Access 2019 as database. My table name is `lrmfile`, field name is `fileno` (short text):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    cmdupdate.CommandText = "Update lrmfile set fileno = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' where fileno =" & ComboBox1.Text & ";"
    cmdupdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmdupdate.Connection = con
    cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Updataed")
    cmdupdate.Dispose()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should learn how to write a parameterized query. This will help you with this error and with other kind of problems like Sql Injection.

Comment: I am a beginner in VB programming. Please convert my code in to parameterized query

Comment: It's not for us to do it for you. It's for you to do some research and make an attempt for yourself. There's information about it all over the web. Being a beginner doesn't mean that you can't use a search engine. If what you try doesn't work, THEN we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be obvious. You are providing two different values for `fileno` and one of them is wrapped in single quotes and the other is not. What do you think those quotes are for and why do you think that you need to use them sometimes but not others? Does wrapping values in quotes relate to type in VB? Why should it not in SQL?